# How to create a simple API using dxa

Tags: dxa, api

I am new to DXA, i want to create an api which return my component data, please any one can suggest any tutorial or any documentation

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange, 

Please add a bit more details looking for DXA Java or .NET which version of Tridion?

Comment: i am using latest version for DXA, i created one component, now i want to read its data using .net web api, i created new controller, in that i m able to get the pageData but not entity. also my component not listed in graphQL, please help to identity the issue